# How to create Navigation tabs to parent and sub parent tabs in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, interactive

Looking to create a interactive PDF with Indesign making parent tabs and sub tabs while going to their page on the Indesign document. I have found different burger menu or navigation tab examples, but they only show one row/column.

[image]